# Get filename into myXhr.upload

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload

I'm uploading pictures in ajax like this :

```
$.ajax({
    // Your server script to process the upload
    url: 'upload.php',
    type: 'POST',

    // Form data
    data: new FormData($('form')[0]),

    // Tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
    // You *must* include these options!
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,

    // Custom XMLHttpRequest
    xhr: function() {
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if (myXhr.upload) {
            // For handling the progress of the upload
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                console.log(myXhr);
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    $('progress').attr({
                        value: e.loaded,
                        max: e.total
                    });
                }
            } , false);
        }
        return myXhr;
    }
});
```

I would like to know the name of current upload file and his input name into "myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) { " function.

It's possible to know here ?

Comment: Can you post the full ajax code?

Comment: I updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find the input inside `progress` event:

```
var inputFile = $('form').find("input[type=file]");
var fileName = inputFile[0].files[0].name;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a264am6m/